# Never Use "On My Mac" for Contacts

Tags: macos, contacts, accounts

I only use Google for my contacts, which works well. However, when I add a contact from, say, the Messages app, the contact gets added to my Mac but not to Google. Then I have to use Cobook to move them... etc.

Is there a way to avoid using contacts "On My Mac" and only use Google contacts?

---

My iCloud has *Contacts* unchecked, which doesn't help.

[image]

Comment: Check in the Menu items of the Contacts app. In Notes, you can uncheck an option that enables the On My Mac account. Not sure if it's the same on contacts. I believe it should be under File > On My Mac account.

Comment: Very cool @IronCraftMan. I see that option now in Notes. Sadly: it's not in Contacts nor in Messages... [oh the consistency]  Thanks for responding on topic.

Comment: Why the downvotes, am I breaking the site rules?